# The riddle of Impression

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
A hint in the air,
What I see of their glare.
Enclosed by the hue,
But beyond my view.
Spirit or scent,
Wrapper with presence;
What word can describe
the immaterial vibe?
```

**What is it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> an aura?

A hint in the air,

> an aura is in the air around us.

What I see of their glare.

> an aura can be bright.

Enclosed by the hue,

> auras are defined by their colors

But beyond my view.

> auras can't really be seen by the eye

Spirit or scent,

> an aura is more spiritual or a "feeling"

Wrapper with presence

> an aura usually surround us. each person with his own aura, like a wrapper defining your presence.

What word can describe
the immaterial vibe?

> an aura is immaterial and a "vibe"